# TypeError: Cannot read property 'Digits' of undefined

Tags: javascript, twilio

I have used the code from Gather User Input via Keypad (DTMF Tones) in Node.js Twilio documentation for getting user input from the call.

but every time I dial in the numbers I'm just getting an error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Digits' of undefined"

Thanks!

code:

```
app.post('/voice', (request, response) => {
   const twiml = new VoiceResponse();

   function gather() {
     const gatherNode = twiml.gather({ numDigits: 1 });
     gatherNode.say('For sales, press 1. For support, press 2.');
     twiml.redirect('/voice');
   }
   if (request.body.Digits) {
     switch (request.body.Digits) {
     case '1':
       twiml.say('You selected sales. Good for you!');
       break;
     case '2':
       twiml.say('You need support. We will help!');
       break;
     default:
       twiml.say("Sorry, I don't understand that choice.").pause();
       gather();
       break;
    }
  } else {
gather();
}

response.type('text/xml');
response.send(twiml.toString());
});
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `python`? It's JavaScript.

Comment: The error means there's no `request.body`.

Comment: The "python" tag is obviously bullocks. Please tag this with the proper language! This is probably the #1 attribute drawing the correct audience to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the below added after you initialize Express?

```
// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Something like:

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

app.use(express.json()) // for parsing application/json
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })) // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded

app.post('/profile', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body)
  res.json(req.body)
})
```

It looks like the [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-gather-user-input-via-keypad-node-js) has it, so maybe it was accidentally omitted in your code?

Comment: Hello, I did initialize Express but still not working.

Comment: Paste your code (without auth credentials)

Comment: Here is the code:
https://ghostbin.com/ywoT3

Comment: I don’t see you added what I called out above, the express middleware is required. app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

Comment: Added it but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: New screen shot. Did you stop the running instance and restart it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242609/discussion-between-fancyclownn-and-alan).